# Inverse of 2D-functions

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Consider a function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and another function $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Does there always exist a function $f$ s.t. $g(f(x),f(y)) = h(x,y)$ ?

I can construct simple cases eg. $g(x,y)=x+y$,  $h(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy$ and then put values to get contradiction in $f(x) + f(y) = x^2 + y^2 + xy$ but I am not sure what is the correct approach to solve the general problem.

I see that for $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ this is straightforward as $f(x) = g^{-1}h(x)$, so $f$ exists if $g$ is invertible.

Comment: I am thinking of something less restrictive first: is there an $f':\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $g[f'(x,y)] = h(x,y)$? And then for some of those $f'$s, for all $x, y\in \mathbb R$, is there an $f$ such that $f'(x,y) = (f(x), f(y))$?

Answer (score 1):

To prove something is not true it is enough to construct an example for which it fails.

Let $g(x,y) = x$ and $h(x,y)=y$. Can you get an $f$ to satisfy your condition?

Comment: I believe the author of the question already knows that their conjecture does not hold in all generality, see their example. I believe they are asking for some conditions on $g$ and $h$ for the result to holds true.